# Is the subspace of affine transformations of a random variable closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $Y$ be a random variable (r.v.) in $L^2(\Omega)$.
Define the subspace $\mathcal L_Y$ as the set of all affine transformation of this $Y$, namely
$$\mathcal L_Y = \{X : X = a+bY, \quad \text{where}\quad  a,b\in \mathbb R \}.$$
Is the subspace $\mathcal L_Y$, which is contained in $L^2$, **closed**?
And what about 
$$\mathcal Q_Y = \{X : X = a+bY+cY^2, \quad \text{where}\quad  a,b,c\in \mathbb R \}.$$

Thanks

Comment: For what concern the second part, i.e. 
$$\mathcal Q_Y = \{X: X=a+bY+cY^2, \quad \text{where} \quad a,b,c,\in \mathbb R\}$$
I assume that $Y$ is at least in $L^4$, otherwise it is not true that $X\in L^2$.

Comment: $\mathcal L_Y$ is a two dimensional subspace of $L^2 (\Omega )$: its base is $\{ 1 ,Y \}$. Since its dimension is finite, it is automatically closed (indeed, every finite dimensional normed space is complete because every norm is equivalent to the euclidean norm). The same for $\mathcal Q_Y$, assuming that $Y^2 \in L^2 (\Omega )$.

Comment: @Crostul: I think you should post this as an answer :)